# SSL Certificate Binding Issue - One or more intermediate certificates in the certificate chain are missing

Tags: iis, tfs, ssl-certificate

I receive the following message after binding our SSL wildcard certificate to our TFS site.

One or more intermediate certificates in the certificate chain are missing.  To resolve this issue, make sure that all of the intermediate certificates are installed.

Does the certificate need to authenticate to the internet?

I've added this wildcard cert to other site binding and this is the first time I've seen this message.

How do I resolve this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported DigiCert High Assurance CA in Trusted Root on both TFS Build and Application server.